# Integrating Out Auxiliary Field of point-particle Polyakov Action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, point-particles

The Polyakov action of a point-particle is

$$S[X,e]=\frac{1}{2}\int d\tau\left(\frac{\dot{X}^{2}}{e}-m^{2}e\right)$$

with the $(−,+,+,+)$ Minkowski sign convention. How to perform the path-integral

$$Z[X]=\int\mathcal{D}e\,e^{(i/\hbar)S[X,e]}~?$$

Comment: Find the equations of motion for the auxiliary field $e$, solve for $e$ and plug it into the action which will then be independent of $e$.

Comment: Are you looking to do this honestly or quickly?  (By 'honestly' I mean using techniques that work for more general path integrals rather than a quick answer, techniques which might be considered overkill in this case but lead to deeper insight.)  And subject to what boundary conditions?